# Simplifying a triple nested sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, asymptotics

I have the sums:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2^j}} 1 $$

This is the sum representation of a triple nested for loop. Normally, I can do these kinds of problems, however due to the $\frac{n}{2^j}$, I have no idea where to even begin on this problem. How can I proceed from here? I would appreciate if you explained each step that you took and maybe the thought process behind it, especially with regards to what is done with the third summation.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of [your earlier question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701350/simplifying-a-triple-nested-sum).

Comment: @amWhy In the linked question, the second $\sum$ sign has upper limit $i^2$, while the quantity in this question is $i$, so I *can't* understand why you call it a duplicate.

Comment: @amWhy I'm sorry that I *can't* understand your reply.  As shown in the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2701350/revisions), only the tags and title of the linked question have been edited.

Comment: @GNU  I am referring to the OPs earlier duplicate post, which should have been edited, and not abandoned to ask yet another question, which is essentially an edit of their last.  Perhaps you will understand this:  "Then [that question] should have been edited, rather than reposting."